# Can I introspect a variable to directly discover what subset it was declared with?

Tags: introspection, raku

Is there a way to introspect a variable to directly find out what subset it was declared with? Here I create a subset, but introspection points me to its base type:

```
> subset Prime of Int where .is-prime
(Prime)
> my Prime $x = 23
23
> $x.WHICH
Int|23
```

I know it has to store the information somewhere, because if I try to reassign a value that doesn't match the subset, it fails:

```
> $x = 24
Type check failed in assignment to $x; expected Prime but got Int (24)
in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

I tried searching through the code, but I quickly get down into files like [`container.c`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/vm/moar/ops/container.c) and [`perl6_ops.c`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/vm/moar/ops/perl6_ops.c) where the C code makes my eyes glaze over. I thought that `X::TypeCheck::Assignment` might help (see [`core/Exception.pm`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/core/Exception.pm)), but it's not clear to me where the `expected` value comes from. (see also [this commit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/4ac10e524316ca426893ee38faada733a8275a27))

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I can check that something matches a subset, but that doesn't tell me if it were declared with a particular subset:

```
> my Int $y = 43;
43
> $y ~~ Prime;
True
```

I'm using Rakudo Star 2017.01

---

Inspired by a Zoffix's use of subsets in [a recent post](https://perl6.party/post/Perl6-But-Heres-My-Dispatch-So-Callwith-Maybe).

Comment: The *should-be* type of a *container* is distinct from the *actually-is* type of value(s) stored in that container. An analogy would be a label on a physical container saying what type of thing should be in the container vs the label on a thing that's actually in the container. So `my Prime $x = 23` creates a symbol `$x` that's bound to a Scalar container with *should-be* type `Prime` that actually contains an `Int`. Most operations applied to a container act on the value(s) in the container, not on the container itself. You need to use `.VAR` as seen in lizmat's answer to get the var's type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value that you stored in `$x` is an `Int`.  It is acceptable to the container (which you typed to `Prime`) because `Prime` is a subtype of `Int`.

So what you're interested in, is not the value in the container, but the *type* of the container.  To get at the container, Perl 6 has the `.VAR` method.  And that has an [`.of` method](https://docs.raku.org/type/Variable#trait_of) to get at the type:

```
$ 6 'subset Prime of Int where .is-prime; my Prime $x; dd $x.VAR.of'
Prime
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. The container `$x` is typed as a `Prime`, which allows it to hold any `Int` that meets the constraints of `Prime`. `$x.WHAT` tells me about its contents, while `$x.VAR.of` tells me the type of the container,